# How do you allow users tag a photo

Tags: plugins

I have created a collectible site and want to allow registered users tag a photo and add it to "Have List" a  "Wish list" or a "Want list".  I would like for the user to be a ble to see the photos they tagged in their profile.  Can someone please point me in the right direction with code, plugins...etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [register_taxonomy_for_object_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/496/can-i-add-a-category-metabox-to-attachment) discussion, this might get you started.