# how can we bring category metabox to Media Library/Upload New Media Page

Tags: categories, metabox

I would like to place the 'categories metabox' found in new post/edit post page in the "upload new media" page. Any clues ?

Answer (score 1):

there was a question very similar to this which as a [**simple answer**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/496/can-i-add-a-category-metabox-to-attachment/649#649) which then turned in to a plugin "[**WOS Media Categories WordPress Plugin**](http://suburbia.org.uk/page/projects.html#wos_media_categories)".

Answer (score 0):

Here is another fantastic plugin for adding custom taxonomies to the media library:
[**http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-tags/**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-tags/)